# How to show (Blank) when using calculated column and DATEDIF when using Sharepoint

Tags: date, sharepoint, calculated-columns

I use below code on a Sharepoint list to calculate banking days but I want it to show (Blank) when there isn't a date in "End Date List", what do I need to change? Today the code shows a number greater than 32k when (Blank).

```
=IF(ISERROR(DATEDIF([End Date List];TODAY();”d”));””;(DATEDIF([End Date List];TODAY();”d”))+1-INT(DATEDIF([End Date List];TODAY();”d”)/7)*2-IF((WEEKDAY(TODAY())-WEEKDAY([End Date List]))<0;2;0)-IF(OR(AND(WEEKDAY(TODAY())=7;WEEKDAY([End Date List])=7);AND(WEEKDAY(TODAY())=1;WEEKDAY([End Date List])=1));1;0)-IF(AND(WEEKDAY([End Date List])=1;(WEEKDAY(TODAY())-WEEKDAY([End Date List]))>0);1;0)-IF(AND(NOT(WEEKDAY([End Date List])=7);WEEKDAY(TODAY())=7);1;0))
```

Since Networkdays function don't work in calculated column I have used this but don't understand where I can change so that if the "cell" is blank, the outcome should also be blank.

Answer (score 0):

Use this formula:

```
=IF(ISBLANK([End Date List]),"",IF(ISERROR(DATEDIF([End Date List];TODAY();”d”));””;(DATEDIF([End Date List];TODAY();”d”))+1-INT(DATEDIF([End Date List];TODAY();”d”)/7)*2-IF((WEEKDAY(TODAY())-WEEKDAY([End Date List]))<0;2;0)-IF(OR(AND(WEEKDAY(TODAY())=7;WEEKDAY([End Date List])=7);AND(WEEKDAY(TODAY())=1;WEEKDAY([End Date List])=1));1;0)-IF(AND(WEEKDAY([End Date List])=1;(WEEKDAY(TODAY())-WEEKDAY([End Date List]))>0);1;0)-IF(AND(NOT(WEEKDAY([End Date List])=7);WEEKDAY(TODAY())=7);1;0)))
```

**Similar thread**: [Blank a column if a condition is met](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/285539/blank-a-column-if-a-condition-is-met/285555#285555)